# Android studio getting stuck on downloading gradle services

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create new project in adndroid studio(installed on Windows 7 OS - 32 bit) (Just sample application- as I am learning Android) and the moment i click on the finsh button on create wizard, it is giving progress-bar showing downloading some zip file from gradle services. 
What I observed is, it took almost 30 minutes and nothing happened. Block is going from right to left and left to right.
Can someone help me to overcome this situation?

Below are the things I tried suggested on stackoverflow forum.(Thanks all for the help) but none worked.

1) Tried to restart studio and then tried to create a project.

2) Downloaded gradle zip file and located at the path it is supposed to be.

3) I closed the studio and restarted it and then tried to open a project that was not created properly last time when i killed process from task manager. Although, I did not get any popup(showing progress of gradle service downloading), I did get some sort of error messages. I think solution 3 is not applicable. Anyway we are opening corrupted project.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Tapan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows, 
Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables
and create a new user variable with the following name and value

```
name = GRADLE_HOME

value = C:\gradle-1.10-all
```

You can replace the value with the path you installed gradle.